# Extracting sentence using NYP as the keyword

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, filter

I need help in this. I've been trying out codes for days regarding about regular expression to extract sentences using NYP as the keyword, the outcome doesn't turn out to be what i expect. what I needed was sentence that contain NYP in it, please help guys its for my project. ! my codes are in the comment box.

```
//readline 
var fs = require('fs'),
    readline = require('readline');

//reading the file
var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('nyptweets38.out'),
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});

//because its a JSON file so I just want the necessary information. the date and text
rd.on('line', function (line) {
    /*console.log(JSON.parse(line));
   create JSON object */
    var TEMP = JSON.parse(line);
    console.log(TEMP.created_at + " : (" + TEMP.text + ")\n\n\n");
})

//here is where the filter starts
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
    Array.prototype.filter = function (fun /*, thisp*/ ) {
        var len = this.length;
        if (typeof fun != "function") throw new TypeError();
        var res = new Array();
        var thisp = arguments[1];
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (filtered.length > 0) {
                console.log(filtered);
                return (filtered.length != -1);
            }
        };
```

Comment: if (filtered.length > 0){    
console.log(filtered);    
return (filtered.length != -1);    
}};

Comment: Please edit your code into the question.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker i pasted the codes in the comment box

Comment: var fs = require('fs'),
    readline = require('readline');

var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('nyptweets38.out'),
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false


});

Comment: rd.on('line', function(line) {
    /*console.log(JSON.parse(line)); */
    /* create JSON object */
    var TEMP = JSON.parse(line);

    console.log(TEMP.created_at +  " : (" + TEMP.text + ")\n\n\n");
})

Comment: if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
        Array.prototype.filter = function (fun /*, thisp*/ ) {
            var len = this.length;
            if (typeof fun != "function") throw new TypeError();
            var res = new Array();
            var thisp = arguments[1];
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (filtered.length > 0) {
                    console.log(filtered);
                    return (filtered.length != -1);
                }
            };


    return res;
  };
}

Comment: function hasNYP() {


var re = /NYP/gi;
var containsNYP = text.search(re) ;
if ( str.search(re) == -1 )
    {
return (containsNYP != -1);
}


//store string as an array to be used in array.filter meth
 var checkLine = new Array();
checkLine[0] = 'NYP';

var filtered  = checkLine.filter(hasNYP);


if (filtered.length > 0){
console.log(filtered);
return (filtered.length != -1);
}};

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker this are the codes ive pasted in the comment box

Answer (score 0):

Regex is overkill here; how about `text.toLowerCase().indexOf('nyp') > -1;`?  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88sZF/)